# HP external keyboard wont work when user boots up laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a user who has an external hp keyboard plugged into a hp laptop. When she boots up the laptop and comes on to the windows login screen the external keyboard does not work and she has to log in via the laptop keyboard. 
Once she has logged in the external keyboard starts working?

Is this an issue with the usb port not coming to life until you have logged in?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If the keyboard is connected to an USB 3.0 port, maybe the driver isn't initialized before the logging.
Have you tried to plug it on another USB port ?

Answer (score 1):

It should detect it, but have try this option it will work, plugin your external keyboard after the boot screen appear(Normally 5-10 Seconds after powering on computer). Or you may attach your keyboard when Username/Password dialog is prompt.

Reason: Because some times your BIOS detects the driver but OS unable to find the attached device so it would not load the driver.

Answer (score 0):

In year 2023, HP Elitebook, the external USB keyboard won't work until you turn off `FastBoot` in BIOS. When enabled it likely skips some USB initialization.